# how can i make my code indented like this for better readability and ease

Tags: json

Just as the title entails I wanna make my code indented like this for better readability. this is my first coding project so I'm not sure how to do that.
[image]

I tried doing what's in the picture and it didn't work.

Comment: @JoanLara That wouldn't be valid JSON

Comment: Post the example as text not an image. A responder shouldn't have to retype.

Comment: Is this a JSON file? Then it doesn't need the `python` tag. They are two different things. And who cares if a JSON file isn't tidy? Its an interchange protocol.

Comment: @tdelaney JSON is often used for config, like by VSCode (ugh). Although it's not clear what OP's using it for.